# TortoiseSVN minify local repo

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, repository

I am working on a very large repository which has lots of binary data stored in it. I only edit a small subset of files.

Is there any way i can delete all the binary files and certain directorys from my local repo and have it so it wont redownload on an SVN update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you use TortoiseSVN 1.7, yes there is a possibility:
on initial checkout inside the dialog there is the option "checkout depht" amd there you can click on "Choose items...". It opens a view to the repository and you can uncheck all files you do not need.

They will not downloaded again, even on  update.